# How to know file is from internal or external storage in android?

Tags: delete-file, storage-access-framework, android-storage

I want to know how to figure out file path is from internal or external storage.

I want to delete a file. Before deleting it i want to check whether it is from internal memory or external.
if file is from internal storage then i can simply delete it like this

```
file.delete();
```

But if file is from external storage (sdcard). Then i would first check permission then delete it through storage access framework.

I'm currently doing like this.

```
            File selectedFile = Constant.allMemoryVideoList.get(fPosition).getFile().getAbsoluteFile();

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (???????????? check if file is not from internal storage ???????????) {
                    List<UriPermission> permissions = getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();
                    if (permissions != null && permissions.size() > 0) {
                        sdCardUri = permissions.get(0).getUri();
                        deleteFileWithSAF();
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle("Please select external storage directory (e.g SDCard)")
                                .setMessage("Due to change in android security policy it is not possible to delete or rename file in external storage without granting permission")
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // call document tree dialog
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }

                } else {
                    deleteFile();
                }
            } else {
                deleteFile();
            }
```

**deleteFileWithSAF()**

```
    private void deleteFileWithSAF() {
        //First we get `DocumentFile` from the `TreeUri` which in our case is `sdCardUri`.
        DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, sdCardUri);

        //Then we split file path into array of strings.
        //ex: parts:{"", "storage", "extSdCard", "MyFolder", "MyFolder", "myImage.jpg"}
        // There is a reason for having two similar names "MyFolder" in
        //my exmple file path to show you similarity in names in a path will not
        //distract our hiarchy search that is provided below.
        String[] parts = (selectedFile.getPath()).split("\\/");

        // findFile method will search documentFile for the first file
        // with the expected `DisplayName`

        // We skip first three items because we are already on it.(sdCardUri = /storage/extSdCard)
        for (int i = 3; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (documentFile != null) {
                documentFile = documentFile.findFile(parts[i]);
            }
        }

        if (documentFile == null) {

            // File not found on tree search
            // User selected a wrong directory as the sd-card
            // Here must inform user about how to get the correct sd-card
            // and invoke file chooser dialog again.

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Please select root of external storage directory (click SELECT button at bottom)")
                    .setMessage("Due to change in android security policy it is not possible to delete or rename file in external storage without granting permission")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // call for document tree dialog
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .show();

        } else {

            // File found on sd-card and it is a correct sd-card directory
            // save this path as a root for sd-card on your database(SQLite, XML, txt,...)

            // Now do whatever you like to do with documentFile.
            // Here I do deletion to provide an example.


            if (documentFile.delete()) {// if delete file succeed
                // Remove information related to your media from ContentResolver,
                // which documentFile.delete() didn't do the trick for me.
                // Must do it otherwise you will end up with showing an empty
                // ImageView if you are getting your URLs from MediaStore.


                getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(selectedFile)));
//                              Methods.removeMedia(this,selectedFile.getPath());

                if (deleteSingleFileCall){
                    Constant.allMemoryVideoList.remove(videoPosition);
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(videoPosition);
                    deleteSingleFileCall = false;
                }

                /*update the playback record to
                 * getFileName() contain file.getName()*/
                for (int i = 0; i < Constant.filesPlaybackHistory.size(); i++) {
                    if ((selectedFile.getName()).equals(Constant.filesPlaybackHistory.get(i).getFileName())) {
                        Constant.filesPlaybackHistory.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //save the playback history
                Paper.book().write("playbackHistory", Constant.filesPlaybackHistory);

            }
        }
    }
```

**This is how i load files of both internal and external storage.**

StorageUtil is library https://github.com/hendrawd/StorageUtil

```
String[] allPath = StorageUtil.getStorageDirectories(this);
private File directory;
for (String path: allPath){
    directory = new File(path);
    Methods.load_Directory_Files(directory);
}
```

All Loaded files in following arraylist.

```
//all the directory that contains files
public static ArrayList<File> directoryList = null;
//list of all files (internal and external)
public static ArrayList<FilesInfo> allMemoryVideoList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**FilesInfo:** Contain all info about file like thumbnail, duration, directory, new or played before, if played then last playback position etc

**LoadDirectoryFiles()**

```
public static void  load_Directory_Files(File directory) {

    //Get all file in storage
    File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
    //check storage is empty or not
    if(fileList != null && fileList.length > 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++)
        {
            boolean restricted_directory = false;
            //check file is directory or other file
            if(fileList[i].isDirectory())
            {
                for (String path : Constant.removePath){
                    if (path.equals(fileList[i].getPath())) {
                        restricted_directory = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!restricted_directory)
                    load_Directory_Files(fileList[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                String name = fileList[i].getName().toLowerCase();
                for (String ext : Constant.videoExtensions){
                    //Check the type of file
                    if(name.endsWith(ext))
                    {
                        //first getVideoDuration
                        String videoDuration = Methods.getVideoDuration(fileList[i]);
                        long playbackPosition;
                        long percentage = C.TIME_UNSET;
                        FilesInfo.fileState state;

                        /*First check video already played or not. If not then state is NEW
                         * else load playback position and calculate percentage of it and assign it*/

                        //check it if already exist or not if yes then start from there else start from start position
                        int existIndex = -1;
                        for (int j = 0; j < Constant.filesPlaybackHistory.size(); j++) {
                            String fListName = fileList[i].getName();
                            String fPlaybackHisName = Constant.filesPlaybackHistory.get(j).getFileName();
                            if (fListName.equals(fPlaybackHisName)) {
                                existIndex = j;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        try {
                            if (existIndex != -1) {
                                //if true that means file is not new
                                state = FilesInfo.fileState.NOT_NEW;
                                //set playbackPercentage not playbackPosition
                                MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                                retriever.setDataSource(fileList[i].getPath());
                                String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                                retriever.release();

                                int duration = Integer.parseInt(time);
                                playbackPosition = Constant.filesPlaybackHistory.get(existIndex).getPlaybackPosition();

                                if (duration > 0)
                                    percentage = 1000L * playbackPosition / duration;
                                else
                                    percentage = C.TIME_UNSET;

                            }
                            else
                                state = FilesInfo.fileState.NEW;

                            //playbackPosition have value in percentage
                            Constant.allMemoryVideoList.add(new FilesInfo(fileList[i],
                                    directory,videoDuration, state, percentage, storageType));

                            //directory portion
                            currentDirectory = directory.getPath();
                            unique_directory = true;

                            for(int j=0; j<directoryList.size(); j++)
                            {
                                if((directoryList.get(j).toString()).equals(currentDirectory)){
                                    unique_directory = false;
                                }
                            }

                            if(unique_directory){
                                directoryList.add(directory);
                            }

                            //When we found extension from videoExtension array we will break it.
                            break;

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Constant.allMemoryVideoList.add(new FilesInfo(fileList[i],
                                    directory,videoDuration, FilesInfo.fileState.NOT_NEW, C.TIME_UNSET, storageType));
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Constant.directoryList = directoryList;
}
```

**Image So reader could easily understand what is going on.**

[image]

Comment: Your scenario is strange. How do you obtain a list of classic file paths from the miro SD card to begin with? If you directly had let the user choose the micro SD card with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and then had scanned the tree you would have a nice content scheme for all video files found.

Comment: `deleteFileWithSAF();` A function without a parameter. No good. You did not post that code but anyhow it would be a hack.

Comment: No. You will not do that. You will try to get a list of content schemes.

Comment: **How do you obtain a list of classic file paths from the miro SD card to begin with?** I just post where i got stuck. Before that i got all videos from internal storage and external storage (successfully) and list it down like in mxplayer. For this i use StorageUtil library [link](https://github.com/hendrawd/StorageUtil) Now when user want to delete any file. It can be either from internal or external storage. Now how to check from path of file that it is from external or internal storage.

Comment: `I just post where i got stuck. `. Yes I know. I know from the beginning. Thats why i said that your approach is strange. You should not begin with classic file paths and then change to SAF. Start with SAF and obtain content schemes for files on micro SD card. Then you can also easily delete them.

Comment: I update my question. Have a look. delteFileWithSAF() code is posted. selectedFile is the path of file which should be deleted and it is global variable. That's why method is without parameter.

Comment: Can i load internal storage file with SAF? If yes then how. Can you send me any link.

Comment: You can use SAF to query the what is called 'primary' partition and also micro SD card and an attached USB drive.

Comment: `deleteFileWithSAF()` Do away with that function. You are on the wrong way.

Comment: What about devices that didn't support SAF?

Comment: Sir it's almost a month, i stuck in this problem. Can you explain little bit in answer that how should i load files and delete, rename that properly. I search a lot before but not found any solution. What i got i implement it and now you say it's not good way to do it. I also update my question with code how i load files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202123/discussion-between-abdullah-khan-and-blackapps).

Comment: You are asking to much. Tackle problems one by one please.

Comment: Ok. Sir i just want to know that what is the proper way to load all storage areas and then load all the files from all storage areas. Which should work on pre kitkat and post kitkat version of android. (If not possible for kitkat then what i need to do for it) Can you answer this in proper way in answer box. So i could understand and could implement the proper way if my approach is not good. Just suggest me a right way, i'm stuck at this point.